# Movesense Accelerometer and Gyroscope scale

Tags: movesense

In the Movesense sensor Documentation, it shows the following specifications for the Accelerometer and the gyroscope:

> Acceleration ±2/±4/±8/±16g full scale
>
> Gyroscope ±125/±245/±500/±1000/±2000°/s full scale

How can I know which one of those scales I am using? +-2 G Or +-16G? or 1000 OR 2000 in Gyroscope?

Which one is the default value? how can I change it?

Thank you

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with movesense, but it would appear this `wbcmd --port COM13 --path Meas/Acc/Config --op GET` is what you're looking for. The documentation here, https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-docs/wiki/EmbeddedSoftware/api/meas/acc.md shows how to change it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation:
https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-docs/wiki/EmbeddedSoftware/api/meas/acc.md

And the default values should be ±8g and ±2000°/s